# Xmonad: Prompt with output of shell commands as completion options

Tags: haskell, xmonad

When I try to put the output of a shell command into an xmonad prompt as a completion option, i.e. as something that can be chosen via the prompt, I keep running compile errors, no matter what I try.

After initially getting a basic custom prompt to work, the following sanity check:

```
mkXPrompt TestPrompt config (mkComplFunFromList config ["a", compltest) testFun 

compltest = do 
    output <- "b"
    return output
```

This may not be terribly idiomatic Haskell, but it works as expected, it compiles and "a" as well as "b" are available options in the prompt. But I just can't get compltest to return the output of a shell command.

I have extensively looked at the source of all instances of xmonad prompt I could find in xmonad.contrib, and I have also checked here and on other websites for questions regarding similar issues, found a few and read them thoroughly.

The problem is that in all these cases, people are either doing something FAR more complex than what I'm attempting to do, or something that is simply very different. If I was better at Haskell I could probably adapt something for my needs, but so far I have spend several hours cobbling together functions and going from one compile error (usually type errors) to the next, no matter what I tried.

What I could so far gather is that I cannot "extract" a string out of an IO String for security reasons, and so should use liftIO in some way. I have also understood that some of the magic should happen in a do block, and that for Xmonad, runProcessWithInput is supposed to work somewhat better than readProcess. But practically applying this knowledge is a different matter.

Here is a tiny subset of the mass of functions I have tried so far, using the command "date" as an example (i.e. the output of the date command at the time of invoking the prompt should be a completion option in the prompt):

```
compltest = do 
    output <- liftIO $ putStrLn $ runProcessWithInput "date" [] ""
    return output
```

```
compltest = do 
    output <- liftIO $ runProcessWithInput "date" [] ""
    return output
```

```
compltest = io $ (runProcessWithInput "date" [] "" >>= readIO)
```

Comment: What went wrong with attempt 2, `liftIO $ runProcessWithInput "date" [] ""`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess bind your key to something like this:

```
do
    output <- runProcessWithInput "date" [] ""
    mkXPrompt TestPrompt config (mkComplFunFromList config [output]) testFun
```

Of course there are more interesting things to do with `output` than making it a singleton list; if `f` is your favorite `String -> [String]` function, then replace `[output]` with `(f output)` in the last line.